# Execute "adb tcpip <port_no>" command without using USB even once

Tags: adb

I am trying to create a backup of all applications in Android, but I don't want the users to connect to USB even for the first time.

Let me first explain what happens when we connect our phone with USB to ADB client:

1. USB Debugging mode is enabled on the phone
2. The phone is connected to a PC using a USB cord. `adb tcpip 9999` command from cmd with ADB already installed. The command helps now switched the ADB daemon (`adbd`) inside the Android phone to listen through TCP/IP protocol
3. Now we can disconnect the phone from the PC
4. Using a terminal emulator application, we can now fire the commands

   1. `adb connect localhost:999`
   2. `backup -all -f /sdcard/dev/bck.ab`

   Now a backup pop-up will open up, you can simply click the backup button. Now we can anytime execute the command in 4.1 and 4.2 until the user restarts the phone, but the problem is I wish to execute `adb tcpip 9999` without PC

Can someone suggest to me how to approach this problem? From where should I start reading, or is there some existing application that can do this on a non-rooted phone?

Comment: There are several apps/widgets available to enable [ADB Wireless](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb#group_840) without an established USB connection. Most of them require root, though – but IIRC there were some that do without. // PS: Here's one doing it without root: [WiFi ADB (no root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fourzero_studio.wifi_adb). Would that fit your needs?

Comment: @Izzy I am trying to execute `adb tcpip 9999 ` without using USB even for the first time, may be sending this command from a cloud server if possible.so a user doesn't need a USB and a PC with ADB.Actually to run this command I need to use a USB connection but I am trying to find a workaround so that I can fire adb backup from the phone itself.Can you suggest is this feasible or not

Comment: That's what I just wrote: user taps an icon to start ADB wireless directly on the device (no USB connection required), and there you go. Have you checked the links I gave? OTOH, if you speak of "cloud", that might be a little more tricky, as the user then needs to have some port forwarding set up on his router.

Comment: Related: [Run adb command inside the terminal emulator or programmatically without root](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/142533)

Comment: @Izzy I am trying to execute the `adb tcpip 9999` command from a non-rooted phone so changing the usb listening mode to tcp mode cannot be done without usb so is there any way to achieve this tcp listening mode for the demon without using the usb ever.

Comment: @izzy, you mentionned com.fourzero_studio.wifi_adb as an app that can enable adb tcpip without root from the phone itself. This app has been removed from the app store. I was wondering if you knew of an alternative as losing adb remote control on every reboot is really hurting my usage. And unfortunately my 50+ phones are unrootable /bootunlockable

Comment: @Shodan may I refer you to my corresponding app listing? [ADB](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb) I never used that app myself, having no need for it, so I cannot tell which one might work how well. But given the list (which is kept updated automatically) you have a selection to choose from and check for yourself ;)

Comment: @Izzy thank you, so much stuff to explore on that page  !  I am using about 16 phones at a time, remote control over wifi over adb/tcpip with scrcpy with a touchscreen PC tablet. So I have a single screen to remotely control all the camera and a single viewfinder. Only problem is, phones sometimes reboot and now I have to disconect them, remove from tripod and bring to a PC. Really ruins the whole wireless control thing !