# How to keep adb TCPIP on after a reboot?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, reboot

I am using android 9 (lineage os 16.0)
Is there anyway of retaining the TCPIP on status after a reboot?
It's annoying to continuously reconnecting it to pc than moving it to charger.
I am aware that if there is other person on the same network it is vulnerable but this device will not leave my home network so that's ok.

Comment: Without root you can't: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216474/218526. With root you can: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232083/218526. Duplicate questions: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232978/218526 and https://android.stackexchange.com/q/157981/218526.

Comment: Having adb running in wireless mode doesn't make the device vulnerable. Device user still has to authorize access whenever a new adb client tries to connect to your device. It increases the risk if the device user is doing multitasking swiftly and the authorisation dialog suddenly pops up and you end up clicking ok because of muscle memory.