# How to run adb and fastboot commands from Termux?

Tags: adb, fastboot, bootloader, shell, termux

Is it possible to run `adb` and `fastboot` commands using Termux terminal emulator? I am wanting to run commands from one Huawei T3 7 to another using USB/OTG cable. Need to unlock bootloader but have no access to a PC or laptop.

Comment: See [Run adb command inside the terminal emulator or programmatically without root](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/142533/96277)

Comment: @Firelord Termux is a bit different from your usual emulator. It is rather similar to a self-contained barebones distribution, instead. Moreover, Google removed the `adb` binary from Android starting with Marshmallow.

Answer (score 5):

This question is nearly a duplicate of [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/142533/218526) which has a detailed answer by @[Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277), except the Termux part. As mention by @[DeathMaskSalesman](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/152843) in comment, Termux is more like a Linux environment, but so far it doesn't have `adb` and `fastboot` in repositories, though [proposed](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/2945). Most probably because they are meant for rooted devices. But you can use static binaries (e.g. [this](https://github.com/shakalaca/fastboot-adb-android/releases) or [this](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/adb-ndk/tree/master/bin)) on Termux like on usual Terminal emulator app. Make sure to set proper environment variables (`TMPDIR`, `HOME` or `HOMEDIR`).

However you won't be able to run each of them without root because only members of [`AID_USB`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/libcutils/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h#81) group are able to read devices in `/dev/bus/usb/` <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/rootdir/ueventd.rc#119))</sup>. Furthermore SELinux restricts unprivileged apps' access to `/sys` and `/dev`.

For `adb` there's a [workaround](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless) if both devices are connected to same network e.g. Wi-Fi or hotspot. `adbd` can be run to listen on TCP socket instead of USB. It's possible if before turning on "USB Debugging" property `service.adb.tcp.port` <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/adb/daemon/main.cpp#211))</sup> is set to some port ([first default](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/adb/transport_local.cpp#52) is `5555`). Apps can't set properties, so to do this using `setprop` on `adb shell` or by simply executing `adb tcpip 5555`, you need to connect the target device to a PC over USB. Then all you have to do from Termux before sending commands is:

```
~$ adb connect <IP>:5555
```

But `service.adb.tcp.port` is reset on reboots and you have to set it again. There is another property `persist.adb.tcp.port` which persists across reboots but it's meant only for [testing](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/autotest/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/server/hosts/adb_host.py#283) and SELinux won't let you set this without root or some system app running with UID `1000`.

Some custom ROMs have built-in toggle to set `service.adb.tcp.port`. But for `fastboot` root is must. However it's possible on Android to access USB OTG devices through [`android.hardware.usb`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary) APIs. [`fastboot-mobile`](https://github.com/google/fastboot-mobile) is an unofficial library from Google to send `fastboot` commands over OTG. [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.sisik.hackendebug) (I have no affiliation) also provides similar limited functionality.

Comment: [Tasker 5.9.2 beta lets you run ADB shell commands without being tethered to a PC](https://www.xda-developers.com/tasker-5-9-2-beta-run-adb-shell-commands-without-tethered-pc)

Comment: @alecxs so how does Tasker sets `service.adb.tcp.port` to `5555` without connecting to PC? On stock Android Dev Options don't have *ADB over network*. So the only way to set `service.adb.tcp.port` is through `adb` because apps cannot set properties. `service.adb.tcp.port` has SELinux context `shell_prop`, so `adbd` can set it. But `persist.adb.tcp.port` doesn't have a defined SELinux context, so it's set with context `default_prop`, which can only be set by `init` on `user` builds. So the both properties can be set permanently only (with root or) on ROMs with modified SELinux policy.

Comment: you must be right. the reddit post say it's using setprop but to me it looks like chicken egg dilemma

Comment: If you restart adb in tcp mode  than Tasker can also send adb commands to Android. This would work so long as the device is not rebooted as that would again require adb restart in tcp mode. All in all, adb support of Tasker would help if you don't ever restart the device.