# Local equivalent to adb install

Tags: adb, installation, apk, terminal, downgrade

With a PC connection and adb, I can install packages by running

```
adb install foobar.apk
```

There is also an option to downgrade a package to an earlier version and keep data (as long the app itself did not introduce any incompatibilities in the later version):

```
adb install -r -d foobar.apk
```

Is there an equivalent local command which I could run from a terminal session (or any other way to downgrade without a PC connection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local `pm` command can do this. You need the following things:

- A terminal app. (`adb shell` will also work, but then you might just as well use `adb install`).
- A way to get root permission on the command line (usually `su`)
- A copy of the APK on the device, e.g. by downloading it using a web browser.

Open the terminal app, then run:

```
su
pm install -r -d /sdcard/download/foobar.apk
```

Command line options are the same as for `adb install`: `-r` will replace existing packages, `-d` will downgrade if necessary.

Comment: `adb shell` doesn't need root access which is a big step for majority of the users. So you can't say them equivalent, but both are commandline solutions. Btw there are workarounds to run `adb shell` on device.

Comment: `pm install` is equivalent in that it installs APKs and is capable of downgrading, just like `adb install`. It is true, though, that `pm` requires root while `adb install` doesn’t. `adb shell` just gets you a command line, which is the same thing that the terminal app does; neither requires root per se. Or did you mean `adb install`? If you have a way to run `adb install` on  the device itself, without requiring a PC connection, feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: `adb install` executes `adb shell pm install` at back end, so they are essentially the same thing. Point is to connect `adb` server to `adbd`, then you may execute any command `adb XYZ`. See this: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216474/218526

Comment: @IrfanLatif why not make this another answer? Both `pm` and local `adb` do the trick, each coming with their own prerequisites. Which of these two is easier depends mostly on your local device configuration.

Comment: It's already answered many times in different questions. You may consider updating your answer.