# How can I enable Android Debugging from a root shell on the phone?

Tags: adb, root-access, usb-debugging

I have a root shell on the phone.

However, no adb service seems running, i.e. the port 5555 is on the device not open<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ telnet 1.2.3.4 5555
Trying 1.2.3.4...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I.e. something what should listen on adb connections, does not run on my Android.

Can I somehow start it from a root shell (on the Android)?

I have Android 10.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Telnet only serves here port testing purpose, obviously `adbd` will be connected by `adb`.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run:

```
settings put global adb_enabled 1
```

You can also start `adbd` service by executing `start adbd` or `setprop ctl.start adbd`. But I prefer the `settings` way because it properly goes through Android framework.

**PS:**

For clarification, `adbd` listens on port `5555` only if ***ADB over Network*** is enabled (from Developer Options, or by running `setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555` on device, or by running `adb tcpip 5555` on PC). In USB mode (which can be switched to by running `adb usb` on PC) `adbd` is not listening on any network port. Some more related details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216474/218526).