# Turn on adb network mode on device without USB connection

Tags: adb, wi-fi, networking, debug

I am debugging an app using a phone-PC combination which has USB issues.  I can successfully establish a wifi connection using 'adb tcpip 555' then 'adb connect 1.2.3.4'

However, sometimes I can't even make the first USB connection to enable the debug listener on the phone.  Is it possible to put the phone adb into listening mode (on wifi) without a USB connection?

Comment: Do you have a rooted device or Android 11?

Comment: Not rooted, android 8.1

Comment: try various apps from google play

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216474/218526

Comment: @irfan -that described how to start TCPIP listening, but still requires an initial USB connection (as described in that post)

Comment: Yes that's the point. The answer explains the limitations; why it's not usually possible to achieve what you are looking for.